# Karate Tests Stuck on Running Forever

Tags: karate

We have currently about 200 test features. We start to face something strange, most of the times tests are just stuck and would not proceed when we run mvn test command as the following:

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags $tags" -Dtest=TestRunner -Dkarate.env=$env
```

Some tests would run as it was perfectly fine. But at some point the rest will just stuck as it it hangs.

We run the tests in parallel using 10 threads.

It stucks like [this](https://youtu.be/JGMP8GV-8Wg)

Anybody experienced similar things? Any ideas what could possibly went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in 0.9.5.RC3 - it is stable to use for API testing, so I recommend you upgrade.

If anyone faces this problem for any other version of Karate, please understand that the best (and possibly *only*) way to troubleshoot or solve this - is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks. I just tried 0.9.5.RC3, however the test is still occassionally stuck from the 10 runs I did.

Comment: Is there a limitation on which maven-surefire version is compatible with the latest karate version perhaps? Thanks

Comment: @Raymond okay, since no one else has reported this - and actually people have confirmed that it is fixed - please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Updating to 0.9.5.RC3 did solve it for me. The last time I tried, I didn't do maven update before re -running my tests. Thanks a lot Peter.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have the same problem as you but I can't comment because of reputation, my project works with Gradle and I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and JDK1.8(at another moment before all this I tried Jetbrains SDK11 but had the same problem, I downgraded to java 8 and everything worked again) on this ocassion I did as peter said and upgraded to 0.9.5.RC4 but still when I execute some of my features they never end, for example, I'm currently working on a very simple feature that calls another feature for login, it works for many other features but for this one it appears to get to the end of its execution and never go back to the caller feature, as I was running out of options I made a new simple project copied the resources folder I store my features in and my run parallel class and tried again but it behaves in the same way, the execution never ends.

I'll upload an image with my screen while it executes as you can see it's been executing for 15 minutes

[projectView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qplHY.png)

Comment: Hi Oscar, it turns out after updating to 0.9.5.RC3, my problem is solved. Perhaps you can try that version instead? Cheers

Comment: Hi Raymond mi problem is solved, I raised an issue in the Karate GitHub page and identified the problems along with Peter Thomas, FYI inside my feature file I had a 
     request =
and that is a mistake you don't need an equal sign to assign the request for the test and it also hangs the test Peter said he would fix that in the next version.

Comment: I faced this issue, actually the test is getting stuck at the cucumber reports generation step, all tests were getting executed. While further debugging I could understand in one of my scenario outlines I had a test data missing which was causing the issue.